# nested STRUCT type in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to form a nested STRUCT type in BigQuery. Facing a syntax error.

Query:
**select STRUCT > ('ind',
    'dev','ind',('ind')) AS dealGeography**

Error: **Struct field 4 has type literal STRING which does not coerce to STRUCT**

Please suggest on how to deal this.

Have attached the schema of this field here.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8dVj.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you want to create this data in your query. This being the case, maybe this will do the trick for you:

```
SELECT STRUCT<id string, type string, name string, address STRUCT<addressCountry string>> ('1', 'test', 'mr_a', struct('addr')) as dealGeography
```

You just need to define the schema for the data and for the inner struct you need to specify it as `struct` as well.